# Deploying with docker-compose. Frontend is not reaching backend

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

So I'm running a web app which consist of 3 services with docker-compose.
A mongodb database container.
A nodejs backend.
A nginx container with static build folder which serves a react app.

Locally it runs fine and I'm very happy, when trying to deploy to a vps I'm facing an issue.

I've set the vps' nginx to reverse proxy to port 8000 which serves the react app, it runs as expected but I can not send requests to the backend, when I'm logged in the vps I can curl it and it responds, but when the web app sends requests, they hang.

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: server
    container_name: node-server
    command: /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon server.js
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    env_file: ./server/.env
    ports:
      - '8080:4000'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    networks:
      - app-network
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2.7-bionic
    container_name: database
    hostname: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=...
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=...
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro
    networks:
      - app-network
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: prod.Dockerfile
    image: client-build
    container_name: react-client-build
    env_file: ./client/.env
    depends_on:
      - server
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  data-volume:
  node_modules:
  web-root:
    driver: local
```

Comment: What are you seeing in your browser network tab? And what are you seeing in the nginx access.log and error.log? And can you show us the nginx config as well? What requests do you expect should go to the backend?

Comment: Also, it appears you posted real DB credentials, you're probably going to want to change those.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. So the host machine nginx logs do not show anything when sending request either through curl or from the web app. The network tab shows that the requests hang until time out. On my local machine when I run this docker-compose file I'm able to send requests from the web app to the backend, but when on a vps they do not go through.

Comment: I think that you are contacting the `server` from the `client` using the external network and no the existing docker network. If you are proxying everything to port 8000 the client does not know how to respond to those request and the server is not accessible from anywhere. Logs from the app and Nginx would also help a lot as I am lucky guessing now

Comment: Nginx logs on the host do not show anything when I send requests, and that makes sense if they are not on the same network. What logs can I show you from the app? 
When I tried without the proxy, I could not reach the nginx container running the web app on 8000. Maybe I'm deploying a weird structure here? How those things usually structured?

Comment: How are you sending requests to your backend? I mean, `VPS_IP:8080` or something else? What about when running in your local environment?

Comment: It is a simple react app. I send requests with axios. When running local on my machine it all works fine. When running on vps, I reverse proxy from port 80 to 8000, to the react app and it can not reach the backend with the same request, but when I do curl localhost:8080 on that machine the backend responds.

Comment: If you're sending your axios request to `localhost`, it's obvious that there is no backend running here to respond. Also if using docker-compose way, note that requests are sent from your browser, so using `server` also doesn't resolve your vps backend. This is why I'm asking on to what endpoint you're sending requests. Can you give an example of calling axios?

Comment: Yeah sure, on axios I've tried 3 things. Sending requests to localhost:8080, to 0.0.0.0:8080 and also to actual ip of the vps:8080, all with no luck, when running locally both first and second options work for me.

Comment: Also tried to http://server:4000, and with the port with no luck.